# tikzpicture infinite width and scale to \textwidth

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to tell tikz to make an image as wide as it needs so it is drawn correctly and then to scale it to `\textwidth` eg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning,arrows.meta,graphs,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\z}[4]{
  \begin{minipage}{2cm}
    \begin{align*}
      Z\{&ini&=&#1\\
         &it&=&#2\\
         &coit&=&#3\\
         &curs&=&#4\}
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow=right,
  edge from parent/.style={sloped,above,draw},
  level distance=7cm,
  sibling distance=4cm]

  \node {\z{p1,p2,p3}{\O}{\O}{p_0}}
  child {
    node {\z{p2,p3}{p_0}{\O}{p_1}}
    child {
      edge from parent node {pop init}
      node {\z{p_3}{p_1,p_0}{\O}{p_2}}
    }
    edge from parent node {pop init}
  }
  child {
    node {\z{p2,p3}{p_0'}{\O}{p_1}}
    edge from parent node  {pop it}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Looks like tikz ran out of space

[image: Tikz decided to stop drawing at some point]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\z}[4]{
  \begin{minipage}{2cm}
    \begin{align*}
      Z\{&ini&=&#1\\
         &it&=&#2\\
         &coit&=&#3\\
         &curs&=&#4\}
    \end{align*}
  \end{minipage}
}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow=right,
  edge from parent/.style={sloped,above,draw},
  level distance=7cm,
  sibling distance=4cm,
  ]
  \node {\z{p1,p2,p3}{\O}{\O}{p_0}}
  child {
    node {\z{p2,p3}{p_0}{\O}{p_1}}
    child {
      node {\z{p_3}{p_1,p_0}{\O}{p_2}}
      edge from parent node {pop init}
    }
    edge from parent node {pop init}
  }
  child {
    node {\z{p2,p3}{p_0'}{\O}{p_1}}
    edge from parent node  {pop it}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with four nodes]

Comment: Maybe a little explanation would be nice.

Comment: It would although it's pretty straightforward: He wrapped the whole `tikzpicture` evnironment in `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}`.

Comment: By the way, I never realised why people end their lines with a comment start.

Comment: The comment start is to prevent the unwanted extra whitespace a linebreak would introduce here.

Comment: @hpekristiansen shouldn't you add another `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}`? (Yes, sometimes it's tricky, I do not know if `\end...` gobbles spaces and I am on my phone now...)

Comment: @Rmano: Yes - you are correct. By test, it does make a very small difference.

Comment: A spin-off question. I do the same a lot, but using ```adjustbox``` instead. Is there any difference? Just as an example: I would typically do 
        ```\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth},center}
        \input{tikzcode}
    \end{adjustbox}```

Comment: @JohnW.deBurgh: Both works by test and both are bad(messes with e.g. text size). I do not know about the differences - see: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-02/msg00445.html